# Windbg how to find size of objects and name of the objects during debug or from dump?

Tags: java, debugging, memory, windbg, heap-dump

I do work on some memory leak and I have really confused about how can I found name of the objects and them actual size from attached process to windbg(This java process).

I have like peace of this from memory tab(Real-16 Byte):

```
77be4109  0.24824256118801986987e+1583
77be4119 -2.5614129038254496960e-4692
77be4129  0.00035486639300841043e-4512
77be4139  1.01282186869268740952e-4257
77be4149  0.00001113192301372295e-4933
77be4159 -7.4761787341726152931e+1384
77be4169  1.20314665648499437676e+0812
77be4179  0.24824256118533248913e+1583
77be4189 -4.0982606461207195136e-4691
77be4199  1.93872828151051165909e-4855
77be41a9 -1.82623583419004015246e-4208
77be41b9 -6.5104196508680929063e-4078
77be41c9  3.65267555224407110105e-4933
77be41d9 -0.00015215514283814482e-2827
77be41e9 -7.23917258927010071181e+2171
77be41f9 -1.91695563942559237891e+0682
77be4209  1.88491305327009472803e+1237
77be4219 -1.47471100734719497676e+0759
77be4229  5.12498463030795446119e-0701
77be4239  3.63165983722201482762e-4305
77be4249  0.00176536862792912144e-4933
77be4259  2.62291322678419124421e-4923
77be4269 -6.19904883189621925339e-3641
77be4279  1.10850108613423590267e-3936
```

And I got peace of this from Dessambely tab:

```
77c1397e 8b1e            mov     ebx,dword ptr [esi]
77c13980 68aa000000      push    0AAh
77c13985 6a08            push    8
77c13987 ff7018          push    dword ptr [eax+18h]
77c1398a e847f4feff      call    ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap (77c02dd6)
77c1398f 89450c          mov     dword ptr [ebp+0Ch],eax
77c13992 85c0            test    eax,eax
77c13994 0f84a3d30200    je      ntdll!EtwSetMark+0x1537e (77c40d3d)
77c1399a 0fb74f06        movzx   ecx,word ptr [edi+6]
77c1399e 6685c9          test    cx,cx
77c139a1 0f8e4a010000    jle     ntdll!RtlFreeSid+0x1ef (77c13af1)
77c139a7 8b4508          mov     eax,dword ptr [ebp+8]
77c139aa 8b4018          mov     eax,dword ptr [eax+18h]
77c139ad 8b500c          mov     edx,dword ptr [eax+0Ch]
77c139b0 8b4010          mov     eax,dword ptr [eax+10h]
77c139b3 0fbfc9          movsx   ecx,cx
77c139b6 0fbf0c4a        movsx   ecx,word ptr [edx+ecx*2]
77c139ba 8d0448          lea     eax,[eax+ecx*2]
77c139bd 50              push    eax
77c139be 8d45f4          lea     eax,[ebp-0Ch]
77c139c1 50              push    eax
```

How can I actually find out which object weight more and name of the object??

Thank you developers.

Comment: I get the feeling you are heading in the wrong direction by using windbg here. If you believe the leak is in your Java code, a tool like [jhat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/memleaks.html#gbywe) or some other heap profiler makes more sense.

Comment: This is application is have c++ code and have java code as wrappers of c++ code. And I want to find out which of c++ object or dll is leaking.

Comment: Since c++, you can try UMDH, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/268343